# Chrome Extension: How to reload/re-execute content script on Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm trying to execute a content script for a certain site (inject a button or change the link) however I would like to do this as the user browses the website.

The problem is that the web page is built dynamically with ajax requests as the user browses.

I had solved this earlier in an extension I had written by actually injecting my JavaScript into the web page.

I was wondering whether there is a better alternative of just being able to register for an ajaxComplete event or something similar in my content script so that I can re-execute.

I can do the following:

```
function listener()
{
    console.debug("listener fired.");
}
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", listener, false);
```

However that fires way too many times during one page load.

Comment: If the website uses hashes (`#...`) or the new HTML5 history API, there are certain events to look for (`onhashchange`, `onpopstate`).

Comment: they are not. For reference the website is [beatport](http://www.beatport.com)

Comment: On Chrome, I can see the URL changing while the page does not navigate away. I suspect they do use the history API. They are using `history.pushState` in the source.

Comment: How do I look for those events? I don't do much JS

Comment: @pimvdb: they simply just pushstate once on the first load. Every click that causes a URL change is not firing additional pushes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no ajax listener that I am aware of, but it wouldn't help much anyway as you need to catch when page is modified, not ajax request is sent/received (page modification usually happens later and can be not tied to ajax request at all).

`DOMSubtreeModified` is the right way to go, just implement some protection from too frequent calls:

```
function listener()
{
    console.debug("listener fired.");
}

var timeout = null;
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    if(timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(listener, 500);
}, false);
```

This way it would trigger `listener` if there was no other events within 500ms.

Comment: I tried the above code. It works! But for every change that I made to the page the listener gets fired so it becomes kind of a infinite loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have also got this problem. it never stop.

Answer (score 5):

The best answer I found was a bit interesting and involved a bit of [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) in between the content scripts and the background.html file.

I'll post the code then explain:

### Background.html

```
  function updatePageAction(tabId)
  {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tabId, {is_content_script: true}, function(response) {
      if (response.is_content_script)
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    });
  };

  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, change, tab) {
    if (change.status == "complete") {
      updatePageAction(tabId);
    }
  });
```

## content_script.js

```
// The background page is asking us to find an address on the page.
if (window == top) {
  chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(req, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (req.is_content_script)
            start_content_script();
            sendResponse({is_content_script: true});
  });
};
```

You want to solve updating or re-executing the script on DOM changes. Luckily the DOM changes involved a URL change (although it was AJAX DOM changes to update the page).
The URL change however fires a onUpdated event. However every tab is firing these "events" and we want to make sure we only care about the one in which we have matched our content scripts too (you can specify a match in the manifest!).

By passing a messgae to the content_script being executed in the current tab, we are asking "Are you my content script? If so, please re-start."