# Improve permission warning for chrome.webNavigation

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When using [`chrome.webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) the `webNavigation` permission is needed. As stated on [Permission Warnings](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings), using that permission makes the installer to show the warning message:

- `Read your browsing history`

In my case, I only want to listen to one specific domain, let's say `domain.com`. So, I need to filter the callback for  `chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener()`.

Now, from the user perspective, they could distrust the chrome extension since "Read your browsing history" is too broad and the extension should only work on `domain.com`.

When a match pattern is used in the permissions, a message like `Read and change your data on all domain.com sites and www.domain.com` is used.

Is there any other way to use `chrome.webNavigation` and only listen to one domain? where chrome extension issues/feature requests should be sent?

---

**Update:** I had to use `webNavigation` in order to support AJAX calls. That is, listen to changes in the DOM and the URL made with AJAX. I solved this particular case by using a **[`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)**. Thus, I could remove the permission. The original question was already reported as a bug by Rob W.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, I've already posted a feature request over a year ago: https://crbug.com/431108 ("Allow extensions to use webNavigation API without webNavigation permission").

> where chrome extension issues/feature requests should be sent?

Report feature requests and bugs at https://crbug.com/new (points to https://bugs.chromium.org).

If you want to get the equivalent effect of `chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted` without using the webNavigation API or adding extra permissions, then you can declare a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the background page when the `window.onload` event fires.

Comment: I already use a content script. I had to use `webNavigation` in order to support AJAX calls. That is, listen to changes in the URL made with AJAX. Do you know any other way? Thanks!

Comment: @IvanRF Then you're using onHistoryStateUpdated, not onCompleted, right? You could inject a script in the page to intercept history.pushState/replaceState (or poll the URL with timers, or monitor the DOM if there is a correlation between the URL change and a DOM modification). Is the domain YouTube? If so then there are some events that you can use to detect navigations (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34100952).

Comment: I'm using `onCompleted`,found it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672230/chrome-extension-content-script-on-facebook). The domain is Facebook and I use the code to track how much time a session is active. I will try `tabs.onUpdated`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325701/chrome-extension-how-to-reload-re-execute-content-script-on-ajax-request) or `MutationObserver`.

Comment: @IvanRF That snippet that you linked is not using the `webNavigation` API, but the `webRequest` API. The `webRequest` API doesn't trigger a permission warning, but it is **not** a reliable indicator for navigations either.

Comment: Sorry, that link was my starting point but I changed my code. I tested `tabs.onUpdated`, works but it's not enough. With `webNavigation.onCompleted` I can listen to the news feed scroll too. So, could a `MutationObserver` on the body work?

Comment: @IvanRF It depends on the website; give it a try and come back if you get stuck.

Comment: Rob, thanks for your help! I updated the question. Finally, `MutationObserver` was the solution for me.